# Synchronizing with server time - jquery countdown plugin and php

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a following code in my php file:

```
<div id="clockTimestamp" class="hidden"><?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];?></div>  
<div id="clock"></div>
```

I am using the jquery countdown plugin from [Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) and am calling it like this:

```
$('#countdown').countdown({until: until, serverSync: getServerTime});
```

And following code in the js file:

```
function getServerTime() { 
    var time = $('#clockTimestamp').html()*1000;
    time = new Date(time); 
    return time;
}
```

Now, my question is: is this approach with the $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']  OK or should I do it like this:

```
function getServerTime() { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: '../../_ajax/getServerTime.php', 
        async: false, 
        dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text);
        }, 
        error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
        }
    }); 
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've solved this now, but for later visitors....

The easiest way to do this would be to use a [jQuery server time plugin](http://jamespfarrell.com/blog/real-server-time-jquery-plugin/98/)

Comment: Not quite sure how it's supposed to work. Will it hook into standard Date and time functions and return them with the correct server time or if I create a Date object with the current time and date, do I have to run that through a function of the plugin? There's no real api documentation for it.

Comment: Your answer is merely a comment, not an answer..and it's **not** easy at all, this so called script you have provided isn't even on github, but in some compressed file on some server, like in the 90s, and there's a lot of code there...no documentation..I wouldn't use such a thing